# Android Camera Parameters

Tags: android, parameters, camera

I would just like to confirm how Android manages the Camera Parameters. Is the camera parameters set by the **setParameters(param)** function of the Camera class is only valid during the lifetime of the camera object. Once the camera object is released, the parameters will be set back to its default values. As long as no setting of parameters is done, **getParameters()** will always get the default camera parameters. Is my understanding correct? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you in advance,
artsylar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, CameraParameters are set using the `setParameters` function.
- Yes, it is valid only during the lifetime of the Camera object.
- Camera Parameters are very much tied to a camera object so when you release a camera object the camera parameters will not have much meaning on their own.
- Yes, `getParameters` will give you the default parameters as long as `setParameters` in not called on the camera object.